# Comment diriez-vous en anglais cette phrase de Proust ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, littérature

Bonjour,

A priori, j'aimerais connaître la traduction anglaise officielle de cette phrase...mais j'imagine que ce serait une demande beaucoup trop surréaliste :)

Je me contente donc de vos propres idées de traduction.

La phrase en question :

**La réalité n'a de sens qu'à travers la perception, réelle ou imaginaire, qu'en a le sujet.**

J'ai essayé de la traduire, mais je suis pas satisfaite du résultat :

Reality makes sense only through individual perception, be it imaginary or real.

(D'ailleurs je suis ni francophone ni anglophone native et je trouve que la phrase n'est pas facile non plus)

Voilà, merci par avance pour vos réponses !

Comment: This question is not about the French language but the English one.

Comment: Cette question devrait être posée (en anglais bien sûr) sur [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Bienvenue sur French Language, s'il vous plait consultez le [Help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I think the real challenge here is the meaning of “qu'en a le sujet” **in French** & if you’d edit your question to indicate this, it might become clearer that your question is about French (i.e., Proust’s meaning of “qu'en a le sujet” in this sentence). Regarding that, your “individual perception” captures it well, although I’d use “only has meaning” instead of “makes sense only”; I’d pluralize “perception” (& therefore also “be **they** imaginary or real”; & I’d add “of it” (=“of reality”):  “Reality only has meaning through [our] individual perceptions of it, be they imaginary or real.”

Answer (score 0):

Reality only makes sense through perception, real or imaginary, that the subject has of it.

Je n'ai pas exactement compris "qu'en a le sujet". J'ai recherché et trouvé ce que j'ai écrit.

Thanks for the translation sumelic!